# laravel 5.1 queue job delay doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

i trying to set a reminder via laravel 5.1 queue service, 
the job executes and works fine, the only problem it's that it not delaying the job, i'm not sure if i'm doing it the right way, can someone tell me what am i doing wrong please? my SetReminder job class looks like that

```
namespace LM2\Jobs;

use LM2\Jobs\Job;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Bus\SelfHandling;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use LM2\Models\Lead;
use LM2\Models\User;

class SetReminder extends Job implements SelfHandling, ShouldQueue
{
use InteractsWithQueue, SerializesModels;

public $user;
public $lead;

public function __construct(User $user, Lead $lead)
{
    $this->user = $user;
    $this->lead = $lead;
}

/**
 * Execute the job.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function handle()
{
    $user = new User(['client_id' => 1, 'name'=>'asdasd', 'password' => '123' , 'email' => microtime().'@gmail.com']);
    $user->save();
 }
}
```

and the controller function calling that job is:

```
 public function setReminder($lead_id, Request $request)
{
    $due_time = $request->input('due_time');
    $message = $request->input('message');
    $user = \Auth::user();
    $lead = Lead::where('_id',$lead_id)->first();
    $lead->reminders = ['message' => $message , 'due_time' => $due_time, 'user_id' => $user->id, 'active' => 1];
    $lead->save();
    $job = (new SetReminder(
            \Auth::user(),
            Lead::find($lead_id)
        ))->delay(10);
    $this->dispatch($job);
    return $lead;
}
```

before calling the function i ran `php artisan queue:listen` at the terminal.
thanks a lot everyone :)

p.s the new user inserted in the handle function it's just for testing it.

Comment: anybody has an idea? :/

Comment: For me it says, delay is not a method.

Answer (score 3):

You probablly have in the env file `QUEUE_DRIVER=sync`. It wont work with it.